# preg_match and reg expression using alphanumeric, commas, periods, exclamations, etc

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am having one hell of a time coming up with a decent way make this if statement search a file for these codes. I set up the text file to read from as such:

**myfile.txt**

```
r)
0Y7
1a6
q.
@g
@(
#a
!P
T[
V}
0,
```

Here is a brief of what I got going.

```
$subject = file_get_contents(fvManager_Path . 'myfile.txt');
if ( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,]+$/',$result['fmbushels_itemCode'], $subject) ) {
```

Basically I am trying to search the text file line by line to see if the whole string exists. They are case sensitive as well.

$result['fmbushels_itemCode'] is from a sql query and always returns a code like the above in the text.

I'd appreciate any help on this. If someone knows a better way of doing this or a different command, I'd be willing to give that a shot as well :)

edit:

```
private function _fvShareBushels() {
$subject = file_get_contents(fvManager_Path . 'myfile.txt');

if (count($vShareArray) > 0) {
$vCntMoves = count($vShareArray);

for ($vI = 0;$vI < $vRunMainLoop;$vI++) {
sell $result['fmbushels_itemCode']);    
}
}
}
```

This is a snippet of a big code. I had to rip most out because of post limitation. The area I could be working with is:

```
if (count($vShareArray) > 0) {
```

If I could make this something like:

```
if (count($vShareArray) > 0 && $result['fmbushels_itemCode'] **is not in** $subject) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do line by line, use the file() function.

```
$f = file(fvManager_Path . 'myfile.txt');
foreach($f AS $line){
    // $line is current line at file
}
```

I'm not to sure if you understand completely how preg_match works. The first parameter is the regular expression pattern, the second is what you want to match the pattern to, and the third is an array of matches. So for every valid pattern matched in the second parameter a new index on the array is created.

I'm not 100% on what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to see if the `$result['fmbushels_itemCode']` exists in the file?

If the above is the correct case you simply just need to do something like:

```
$f = file('myfile.txt');
array_map('trim', $f);
if(in_array($result['fmbushels_itemCode'], $f)){
    // success
}
```

Comment: sorry adding a comment doesn't have the feature for posting like the question itself

Comment: I think I may need just the opposite. Instead of foreach($f AS $vShare['item']) { I need something like foreach($f !AS $vShare['item']) { But !AS gives an error